# Can't serve files other than .py files

Tags: apache2, raspberry-pi

I have `apache2` on a Raspberry Pi.  My application is in the `/var/python` folder.  I can serve .py files from that folder without problems, but .css or .txt files get a 500 error. These files have r and x rights to the world.

My configuration file is as follows:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /python/ /var/python/
    <Directory /var/python>
            Options All
            AddHandler cgi-script .py
    </Directory>
```

The error log gives a cryptic "Premature end of script headers".

What could be the problem?

Comment: css and txt files must NOT have x permissions

Comment: Thanks.  Removed the x but problem remains.  txt files with x in /var/www work fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that the server is trying to parse css and txt files as cgi scripts. 
This is caused by the `ScriptAlias` directive which marks the target directory as containing CGI scripts. You already have an `AddHandler` directive for the python directory, so the ScriptAlias is redundant.

Solutions:

1) Replace `ScriptAlias` with just `Alias`

2) Move all non-cgi files to another directory, outside of `python/`. In the second case, you can remove the whole `Directory /var/python` block.